# Python | Function Running Twice When Called

Tags: python, function, class

I've been having this issue where my function is being ran twice upon being called once from a class. Some context before I get into the issue. I'm writing a class that runs functions from the file that is using the class by using `__import__(argv[0].replace('.py', ''))` to import functions from the file.

I have a function called `on_ready()` that's supposed to be called when the class **init** has finished everything it needs to.

A snippet of my code showing the `__init__`:

```py
self.file = sys.argv[0]
self.file_data = __import__(self.file.replace('.py', ''))

with open(self.file) as file:
  if 'on_ready()' in file.read():
    self.file_data.on_ready()
```

And snippet showing the file which calls this class

```py
def on_ready():
  print(client.last_scanned_inbound)
  print('======')
```

Running the following code activates the `on_ready` function twice. Any solutions? (The class filename is not the same as the file from which the `on_ready` function is in)

Also, it's only the `on_ready` function that's been having issues, there are several other functions that are working fine.

Comment: Needs an MRE, but it seems likely that your `__import__` has an unintended side effect.

Comment: Is there a call to `on_ready()` in the file that defines that function?  Importing the file would execute that call.

Comment: Hi walker. When asking questions on SO, it's important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Other users are pointing out that the problem is most likely in code that you haven't posted. Can you try providing a minimal amount of code that completely reproduces your problem?

Comment: There is no call to `on_read()` in the file that defines the function, only the function being defined.

Comment: The minimum needed to replicate is just the code I sent, the top one just needs to be put in a class and in the main file, import the class and add the on_ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by putting `if __name__ == '__main__'` before I ran the module to prevent it from running when I imported it.